# Is it true that $\int_0^1 |f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x)|dx \le |\int_0^1 (f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x)) dx|$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Is it true that if $f_n(x) = x^n \in C[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1 |f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x)|dx \le |\int_0^1 (f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x)) dx|$ ?

I suppose, that it is true, and generally for any $f,g$ we have that $\int |f(x) - g(x)|dx \le |\int (f(x) - g(x)) dx|$ but I don't remember name of these properties. Am I right?

Comment: You're general proposition is false but you can observe that $f_n(x)\le f_{n+1}(x) $ for all $x\in[0,1]$. What do you get from this observation ?

Comment: @user37238 You must mean $f_n(x) \ge f_{n+1}(x)$

Comment: @Macavity Yes of course !

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true.
We have:

$$|\int f | \leq \int |f|$$

It's a consequence of the triangle ineqaulity.

Comment: So how can i prove that $f_n$ is Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @Tomek the inequality is true for your particular case of $f_n$, but not in general.

Comment: So why it is true in my case? How prove that?